# Cannot see all elements within a MIB using snmpget/snmpwalk

Tags: snmp, net-snmp, mib

I am using NET-SNMP (V5.6.1.1) on windows to read my MIB with snmpget & snmpwalk.  When I try accessing the MIB I can only see some of the elements.  I know the MIB is good since my colleague can extract the same revision of the MIB from the repository and can see all elements within the MIB.  We are using the same SNMP command syntax to query the data.  I have compared the MIB and snmp.conf files between his machine and mine and they are identical, so can only assume that it is due to a difference in the configuration of our respective PCs.  I’ve also checked for any differences in the Environment Variables between our machines, but can see nothing obvious.  Is there anything in the machine configuration that might explain why I can only see part of the MIB?

**Edit:** The MIB is implemented as a single bespoke executable, with the data held in a number of tables, for example:

```
mibTableA.parameter1
mibTableA.parameter2
mibTableA.parameter3
```

---

```
mibTableB.parameter4
mibTableB.parameter5
```

---

```
mibTableC.parameter6
mibTableC.parameter7
mibTableC.parameter8
```

None of these tables are dependant upon the availability of system hardware, etc.  These tables can also be accesses via an RTA interface using PSQL queries, and using the RTA interface on both my machine and my colleague’s machines, I can see all the tables/parameters.  Yet, for instance, accessing the MIB via SNMP I can only see the mibTableA on my machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.  There are some scalar fields in the MIB which define the table sizes and these had not been initialised correctly, but instead were picking up old values stored in tables in a C:\Documents and Settings\user\Application Data folder.  Hence the difference in behaviour between my machine and my colleagues.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to identify which are the missing ones on your box. Show some examples in your question so that others can guess what can be the cause.

Second, SNMP query result is indeed machine dependent. For example, if your machine has less network adapters than your friend's, then it is reasonable some objects are missing.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I've added some more detail as requested.